# API design: Auth0 for authentication and internal authorization

Tags: authentication, api-design, auth0

I am creating a iOS native app that talks to a Flask API.

My plan is to have the iOS front-end handle log in with Auth0 lock. Afterwards, the front-end would store the JWT in local memory and use that on every API request.

On the back-end I plan to have a User table with both an internal ID field and a Auth0 ID field. Per API request I would look up the user via the Auth0 ID and then use a library like [flask-bouncer](https://github.com/bouncer-app/flask-bouncer) to handle resource authorization.

1. Is this a valid approach?
2. Are there any out of box features of Auth0
   that I am rebuilding? If so what are the advantages of using the
   Auth0 version?
3. Are there any future implications that I am missing
   with this approach?
4. What are the advantages of using Auth0 instead of building it myself following something like [this](https://realpython.com/token-based-authentication-with-flask/)?
5. Anything else to consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a valid approach?

Depends on what you call valid. But it would work, yes.

> Are there any out of box features of Auth0 that I am rebuilding? If so what are the advantages of using the Auth0 version?

You're not using authorization using scopes. See [Auth0's tutorial for Flask](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/python/01-authorization).

> Are there any future implications that I am missing with this approach?

That's a broad question that I wouldn't know an answer for.

> What are the advantages of using Auth0 instead of building it myself following something like this?

You do not have to worry about signup, login, verifying emails, bruteforce protection, resetting passwords, MFA, etc. You get all of those things out of the box. But... some more complex things might require additional effort on your side.

> Anything else to consider?

Make a clear decision on where you're storing what info and whether you want to store your users in your database at all. An easy pitfall is to have multiple sources of truth for certain data that's both in Auth0 and your database (e.g. first and last name). Also see the [User Data Storage Best Practices](https://auth0.com/docs/users/references/user-data-storage-best-practices).

Comment: The appropriate usage of scope is a bit of a point of confusion for me.

Say I wanted to make a TODO list app and I wanted to allow users to manage their own TODO lists, and view TODO lists other users share with them. How would I do this with scopes?

In my mind, scopes are more useful for giving API all or nothing access to a resource type v.s. a subset "viewable" by a specific user i.e. why the "profile" scope is a common use case. Am I understanding this incorrectly?

Comment: If you want to set authorization on individual items instead of actions, you're right, Auth0 scopes are not going to help you.